# bash value of $LINE is not showing when defined like val=`$LINE`

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following bash script for some reason $LINE value is not coming on val=. I can see the line from file is read can be display by each $LINE but when defined in the val.. is not showing.

```
  #/bin/bash
  while read LINE
  do
       echo "Processing:" $LINE
       val=`ldapsearch -h localhost -w test -z 0 -x -b 'dc=test,dc=org' -D "cn=admin,dc=testing,dc=com" id=$LINE | grep val`
       echo $LINE "," $val
  done < inputfile.txt
```

any idea what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Take one example line. Replace `$LINE` with the (quoted) text. Then run the `ldapsearch` command. Does that give the intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your issue it would seem like you're encountering an issue with the results of your `ldapsearch`.

*Potential fix #1*

For starters I'd enable verbose output so you can see how the backtick portion of your command is getting expanded.

```
set -x
val=`ldapsearch -h localhost -w test -z 0 -x -b 'dc=test,dc=org' -D \
     "cn=admin,dc=testing,dc=com" id=$LINE | grep val`
set +x
```

*Potential fix #2*

I'd also change it so that it uses `$()` notation instead of the backticks.

```
val=$(ldapsearch -h localhost -w test -z 0 -x -b 'dc=test,dc=org' -D \
     "cn=admin,dc=testing,dc=com" id=$LINE | grep val)
```

*Potential fix #3*

Also I'd quote the contents of `$LINE` when passed to `id=`.

```
val=$(ldapsearch -h localhost -w test -z 0 -x -b 'dc=test,dc=org' -D \
     "cn=admin,dc=testing,dc=com" id="$LINE" | grep val)
```

*Potential fix #4*

Lastly I'd try changing the pipe from `|` to `|&` so that you're parsing both STDOUT and STDERR from `ldapsearch`.

#### General tip

You can always enable full verbose output from Bash by appending the switch `-x` to the shebang line.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
...script...
```

Comment: this is great info. It  helps me to narrow down the problem. I noticed there is \r in $LINE which is massing the ldap query. what is the best way to remove this line feed from this variable. I am $LINE | tr "\r" " ". which is kind of working

Comment: @Salton - yes `tr` would be the way to go. Do a `| tr -d '\r'`. That'll delete any `\r`'s from your output.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a quoting problem. Instead of `id=$LINE` you should (in general) use `id="$LINE"`. Same for `echo $LINE`.

Comment: no sir. not that easy.. I tried that didn't work.. it is frustrating.